# How to make an infinite ViewPager2 with horizontal sroll?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager2

I would like to have a horizontal scrolling carousel that will display news. Those news I would like to be like an infinite loop of cards. When I am on first cards I would have the ability to go back to the last and when I am on the last to be able to go back to the first card.

At the first run of the app where no scrolls have been taken place, when I scroll from the first to the second card, it appears the last card next to the first card but it scrolls to the second.

When I try to scroll from the first to the last card, the last card appears also but it never scrolls like the first scenario. So I have to scroll two times to go from the first to the last. One time to appear the last card and another one to scroll from first to the last card.

I would like to scroll immediately if it is possible.

Here is my code:

```
    newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(newsList);
    newsViewPager.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
    newsViewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
    newsViewPager.setClipChildren(false);
    newsViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    newsViewPager.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

    CompositePageTransformer newsTransformer = new CompositePageTransformer();
    newsTransformer.addTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(40));
    newsTransformer.addTransformer(new ViewPager2.PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
            float r = 1 - Math.abs(position);
            page.setScaleY(0.85f + r * 0.15f);
        }
    });

    newsViewPager.setPageTransformer(newsTransformer);
```

Here is my OnPageChangeCallback:

```
 private ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback onPageChangeCallback = new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            int currentEventItem = eventsViewPager.getCurrentItem();
            int lastRealEventItem = eventsViewPager.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 2;
            if (currentEventItem == 0) {
                eventsViewPager.setCurrentItem(lastRealEventItem, false);
            } else if (currentEventItem > lastRealEventItem) {
                eventsViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
            }

            int currentNewItem = newsViewPager.getCurrentItem();
            int lastRealNewItem = newsViewPager.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 2;

            if (currentNewItem == 0) {
                newsViewPager.setCurrentItem(lastRealNewItem, false);
            } else if (currentNewItem > lastRealNewItem) {
                newsViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Here is my newsAdapter:

```
   public NewsAdapter(List<New> allNewsList) {
    this.allNewsList = allNewsList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.new_cardview, parent,false);
    v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int itemCount = getItemCount() - 2;
    int adjustedPosition = (position  + itemCount) % itemCount;

    holder.newTitle.setText(allNewsList.get(adjustedPosition).getTitle());

    if (allNewsList.get(adjustedPosition).getImage().isEmpty()) {
        Picasso.get().cancelRequest(holder.newImage);
        holder.newImage.setImageDrawable(null);
    } else{
        Picasso.get().load(allNewsList.get(adjustedPosition).getImage()).into(holder.newImage);
    }



    holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
            AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) holder.view.getContext();

            bundle.putSerializable("newsList", (Serializable) allNewsList);
            activity.getIntent().putExtra("title", allNewsList.get(adjustedPosition).getTitle());
            activity.getIntent().putExtra("content", allNewsList.get(adjustedPosition).getContent());
            activity.getIntent().putExtra("date", allNewsList.get(adjustedPosition).getDate());
            activity.getIntent().putExtra("image", allNewsList.get(adjustedPosition).getImage());


            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController((Activity) view.getContext(), R.id.nav_host_fragment);
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_newDetailsFragment);
        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int limit = 3;
    return Math.min(allNewsList.size(), limit  + 2);
}
```